# List of 3 integers that gives 'simple' standard deviation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, standard-deviation

Does anyone know a list of 3 integers that gives a 'simple' answer when you calculate the standard deviation? Ideally it would be an integer that is not too great. For example when I have the vector
$$\vec x=(1,2,3)^T$$
The standard deviation is
$$\sigma_x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\langle x\rangle)^2}=\sqrt{2/3}$$
This has a square root and so it is not a simple answer. Ideally it should be easy to calculate so the coefficients should not be too high.

Comment: Do you mean three different integer numbers whose squares sum a square multiple of $9$?

Comment: $(2,2,2)^T{}{}$?

Comment: You might be interested in Frank J. Dudek (1981) Data Sets Having Integer Means and Standard Deviations, Teaching of Psychology, 8:1, 51, DOI: 10.1207/s15328023top0801_17 https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/s15328023top0801_17?journalCode=htop20

Comment: Also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375824/does-there-exist-a-process-to-build-a-list-of-numbers-whose-standard-deviation-i

Comment: @peterwhy No trivial answer ;) The aim for this question is to have a nice set of numbers that I can give as an example when calculating the std.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only triples of rationals $(a,b,c)$ such that the variance $(2/9) (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - ac - bc)$ is the square of a rational are the trivial cases $a=b=c$.

Since variance is invariant under translation, we may assume wlog $c = 0$, and since variance is homogeneous of degree $2$ we can multiply by a common denominator to assume $a$ and $b$ are integers such that $2 (a^2 + b^2 - ab)$ is a square.  Since this is even, $a^2 + b^2 - ab$ is even, but that requires $a$ and $b$ to be both even.  Then the same condition is true for $a/2$ and $b/2$, and we get an infinite descent.

Comment: Ah so it can't happen. Too bad